# How to know in RabbitMQ cluster which node is oldest?

Tags: cluster-computing, rabbitmq

I have a cluster of nodes setup where each queue is mirrored to every node. Initially all my connections enqueue and dequeue happen at the first node, however in case of it shutting down the client needs to shift to another nodes, How to know from the array of node like

`Address[] addrArr = new Address[]{ new Address(hostname1, portnumber1)
                                 , new Address(hostname2, portnumber2), ...};`

which node is oldest? As it will be more similar to the node that died.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using RabbitMQ's [Highly Available Queues](http://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html) (if not, you should seriously consider it).  In this case, RabbitMQ handles everything automatically.  To quote the documentation,

> If you stop a RabbitMQ node which contains the master of a mirrored-queue, some slave on some other node will be promoted to the master

So, you do not have to worry about it.  Queue contents is automatically replicated and if a queue goes down for some reason, another copy of the queue will become the master queue (and this queue will be *identical* the the failed queue, not just similar).

Comment: To assist the OP with their 'which node to move to' quandary, it's worth mentioning that you should be presenting your cluster to your clients as a single virtualised IP from a suitable load balancer. You shouldn't need to have to manage nodes from code. And yes, Rabbit's HA clustering is most definitely the way to go.